# Как добавить поставщика OLEDB 12.0 в с#

Tags: c#, база-данных

столкнулся с такой проблемой. В С# Form отсутствует поставщик OLEDB 12.0.... На моем ноуте присутствует и все там норм подключается к БД Access. Но увы на ПК нет этого поставщика... и не могу подключиться..
Уже и офис переустанавливал, и драйвер ставил на access "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" , и разрядность менял туда сюда везде..
На данный момент везде стоит 64 бит..

Так же натыкался на один код  который показывает присутствует ли этот поставщик или нет , но он показывает что присутствует а при подкл источника данных там такого пункта нет...

```
    DataTable table = new OleDbEnumerator().GetElements();
            string inf = "";
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                inf += row["SOURCES_NAME"] + "\n";
```

[image: Вот тут должны быть поставщик 12.0]

[image: А тут вот показывает что типо присутствует, однако при создании подкл появляется ошибка]

Comment: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

Comment: Увы но не помогло(((

Comment: Попробуйте прописать строку соединения к БД вручную.

Comment: Кстати вручную все срабатывает... а через конструктор подключения не получается...

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулся , но решил эту проблему удалив 64 бит офис и установив 32))